# Isn't it true that all types of spikes will fit on all types of running spike shoes?

Tags: running, running-shoes, shoes

Initially, I'd thought that all types of spikes will fit on all types of spike shoes, but after reading this article

> If you are buying track shoes with spikes, check the size of the
>   spikes. Spikes that are too long will stick in the rubberized surface
>   of the track more than smaller spikes, which can slow down your time.
>   If the spikes are longer than what you need, ask the store clerk **if
>   the shoes come with a smaller spike size.** [<sub>(Source)</sub>](http://www.mademan.com/mm/how-choose-right-track-running-shoes.html%3a)

I'm now confused about that matter.

I'm sure that there are different types of spikes (for short-d / mid-d / long-d), and I'm also sure that there are different types of spikes (for short-d / mid-d / long-d),

so basically I was wondering does all types of spikes (short-d / mid-d / long-d) fit on all types of running spike shoes (short-d / mid-d / long-d)? If I have a spike shoe, I can be sure that any individual spikes that I will buy will be able to fit in that shoe right?

==
PS: I'm talking about metal spikes here.

Comment: isn't matter thatyour spike size is more bigger than what you are wearing now? example if i wear UK 9 but i bought Uk 9.5

Comment: They are talking about the length of the spike, not the size of the screw shaft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all spikes fit all track shoes (assume you are using track spikes), but the question isn't if they all fit, the question you should be asking is "what kind of spikes should I use in my track shoes?".  If you are running distance, or even middle distance, you want short spikes.

The actual size will vary, depending on your shoe.  Some shoes have a recessed socket for the spikes, others have one that extrude from the bottom of the shoe.  If the socket is recessed, you may want a pike that is 1/8" longer.  Typically a D or MD shoe should only have a 1/8" - 1/4" spike.  You're not running as fast, and though you are on your toes, it's not quite the same as a sprinter.  Still, as a sprinter you don't want long spikes.  Longer spikes can cause you to catch your toe and send you head over heals.

Javelin and Cross Country typically mandate longer spikes.

The only thing you have to worry about spikes from a compatibility standpoint is the way you install the spikes.  There are two different types of spike keys based on the types of spikes.  Some are hex and others are a simple wedge.  If you have both types of spike keys you do not have to worry about this.  However the threads of the spikes will all be the same.

Comment: thanks for the help =D btw do you know why some shoes have 5 holes while others have 7 holes for spikes?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to reply to an old thread here. I couldn't comment directly to Pacerier, but I think 4-5 hole shoes are generally for longer distance and easier turn over.  7-8 hole are for sprinters that need more traction.